# Android Studio Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am getting this error,  Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0 I have been looking on here and tried changing it to other variations of that line but so far no luck, why do I keep getting this error?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try compileSdkVersion 28 to 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we don't consider the typo in :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0'
```

<sub>Change it to:</sub>

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Then, you probably should use the latest version for the Firebase dependencies to avoid those `Please fix the version` errors:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
```

Then rebuild the project. Also, remember to use latest gradle to avoid couldn't found such dependency or etc.

Inside `build.gradle` of the project (inside your project root directory):

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

        // replace it with the 3.2.0 version
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // update this too
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am now getting Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.4.

Comment: Yes. I have added the google services latest version. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `appcompat-v7` dependency that you have added to the `build.gradle`.

Change `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7.28.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Notice the `:` between `appcompat-v7` and `28.0.0` that separates the artifact name and the version.

Comment: Thank you very much